# How to disable formatting of Gherkin tags in Rider?

Tags: c#, tags, gherkin, rider

I faced an issue with the formatting of Gherking tags in Rider IDE.

I'd like to have them placed in one line, but after applying Reformat Code tags are placed in a column, one under the other.
It doesn't suit me, I'd like to keep them in one line after applying Reformat Code.

[Tags before formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAvph.png)

[Tags after formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFlbY.png)

I spent lots of time looking for an option in Code Style settings to disable this formatting but I couldn't find it.
I will be grateful if someone can help.